# Best approach to have context sensitive menus in fragments

Tags: java, android, menu

I have one fragment that deals with previewing and so taking pictures, and on that fragment I want to have an option in the action bar have an item.

On some of the other fragments I would like to have items that will be in common, but only if not on a large device (tablet), as the tablet will have a fragment that handles controlling activities.

So, since I only have one Activity in my application, what is the best way to have context sensitive menus in the actionbar, in a fragment.

And how do I best show items only if on a small device?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the best approach is to just have the fragment add the items to the actionbar as described here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar

But, it will also be necessary to look for an id that is unique to the non-large layout to decide if certain menu items should be included.